# ID element to not display

Tags: toggle, visibility

I have this code:

```
function showForm()
{
    var a=document.getElementById("opts").value;
    if(a==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("f1").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("f2").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f3").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f4").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f5").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f6").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f7").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f8").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f9").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f10").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f11").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f12").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f13").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f14").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f15").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f16").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f17").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f18").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f19").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f20").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f21").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f22").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f23").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f24").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f25").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f26").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f27").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f28").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f29").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f30").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f31").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("f32").style.display="none"
    }
    if(a==2)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get this js to be smaller?

I use it for the website [www.borrani.com](http://www.borrani.com) in the double dropdown selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop could certainly make it smaller:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
    document.getElementById('f' + i).style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById('f1').style.display = 'block';
```

You might even try [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) to explicitly identify your elements based on a pattern, assuming you can define a unique pattern for only the elements you want:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="f"]');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById('f1').style.display = 'block';
```

It may be slightly more code, but it de-couples the code from the specific number of elements being identified.